# before each() error in enzyme unit testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I'm writing a test using enzyme for react application. When I tried to write a test for a component under several layers, `before each()` error comes up.

In the terminal, it says `✖ "before each" hook for "Tests Logout component rendering"`

Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Logout from 'components/Navbar/Logout'

describe('(Component) Logout', () => {
  let _wrapper

  const render = () => {
    _wrapper = shallow( <Logout /> )
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    render()
  })

  it('Tests Logout component rendering', () => {
    expect(_wrapper.find('.logout').length).to.equal(1)
    expect(_wrapper.find('div').length).to.equal(1)
    expect(_wrapper.find('i').length).to.equal(1)
  })
})
```

I don't receive any error for another component which a single layers like `components/Input`. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a more specific error?

Comment: no. it says `✖ "before each" hook for "Tests Logout component rendering"`

Comment: When running, is `render` defined within `beforeEach`?

Comment: Try `before`, since it's only been rendered once, `beforeEach()` is an overkill, unless you're gonna be testing against different prop values.

Comment: I tried `before`. It didn't work. I got en error. `"before all" hook
      PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)
    Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Logout)".`